# suppress suspicious code in one function

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm getting some suspicious code warnings in one function. I want to suppress warning errors of type `suspiciousCode` in that function - not the whole file.

[Google closure wiki](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings) tells me to use  `@suppress {suspiciousCode}` but that doesn't work and gives me another warning: `JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. unknown @suppress parameter: suspiciousCode`.

important lines of code:

```
/**
 * This is a function where type checking is disabled.
 * @suppress {suspiciousCode}
 */
(function(a,b){
```

Could this have anything to do with the wrapping function?

EDIT:

These are the error codes I'd like to suppress:

- `JSC_SUSPICIOUS_SEMICOLON: If this if/for/while really shouldnt have a body, use {}`
- `JSC_USELESS_CODE: Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.`
- `JSC_USELESS_CODE: Suspicious code. This code lacks side-effects. Is there a bug?`

I've checked the warnings and they to exactly what I want.

Comment: Possibly, though I wouldn't have expected a _parse error_ even in that case.

Comment: `Warning about things like missing missing semicolons and comparisons to NaN` I wonder why these are considered "suspicious" o.O

Comment: i guess they are things you might want to do sometimes, but not allways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an oversight, it will be fixed in the next release.  You can get it now by building from source.  Here is the change adding it to list of diagnostic groups that can be used for suppression:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/diff?spec=svn155a2e434bde40d325bbc92cdbe988ece4582e2c&r=155a2e434bde40d325bbc92cdbe988ece4582e2c&format=side&path=/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/parsing/ParserConfig.properties

Answer (score 2):

I believe that suspicious code is not supressable because it indicates situations that are syntactically correct but are the source of many common code errors. For instance here's the discussion on comparison to NaN: https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=857. In your case the compiler is telling you that if you wish to have a for loop with an empty body, use a set of empty `{}` to indicate this as it is much clearer and less likely to be unintended.

The uselessCode diagnostic group will suppress the two "JSC_USELESS_CODE" warnings. In general, the compiler assumes that getprop calls do not have side effects, so if you do not use the value it will warn. This is not always the case and so it cannot remove the code and instead warns you about the issue.

Comment: Are you sure? That seems to be a completely different warning.

Comment: Sigh read too fast. Yes you are correct - they are different. I'll update the answer.

Comment: but it doesn't break code? Everything works but the error messages are annoying me.

Comment: Two of your warnings are supressable with the uselessCode group. The semicolon after the for loop would need fixed or ignored. The compiler warns because an accidental semicolon in that location is syntactically correct, but rarely intended. They can cause hours of troubleshooting headaches.